# How to replace incorrectly unescaped double quotes in json string

Tags: java, string

I have json string which has double quotes in one of the value are not escaped.

Can any one please help me to identify it and escape. here is the example.

```
String s="{\"name\":\"son"o"o\",\"salary\":600000.0,\"age\":27}";
```

I want to escape the double quotes surrounded by "o".

Comment: First of all, your code snippet is a syntax error. It ends right after `...\"son"`, and the Java compiler should complain about `o` being an unexpected token. Please make sure you post the _real_ data you have a problem with. Before that, answering your question is impossible.

Comment: Sure, I have one third party tool which connects oracle and gets the data which passes resultset as json string  to mapped class, that json string has double quotes in one of the value so I am getting error while parsing it. I am trying to replace that unescaped “ with escaped.

Answer (score 0):

In JSON, double quotes need to be escaped with a backspace (`\"`), so the correct sequence is:

```
String s = "{\"name\":\"son\\\"o\\\"o\",\"salary\":600000.0,\"age\":27}";
```

Here we have:

- `\\` to insert a backspace
- `\"` to insert a double quote

This results in the following JSON output:

```
{"name":"son\"o\"o","salary":600000.0,"age":27}
```